# Magento - how to get products from a category outside the root category

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to get products from a category that is outside of the store default root category.

The following code will work if I shove in the ID from a category that is within the store root, but there are a set of categories (here the $_supplierData['supplier_category']) that are outside of the store front root category... if I put in the id for those catagories... no products are loaded into $_collection

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load($_supplierData['supplier_category']);

$_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->load();
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to load these products into a collection?  I can't push the category into the store root -- that's a design decision made by another developer on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_supplierData['supplier_category'])
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```